# Filtering out switching noise from 3 phase mains

Tags: noise, three-phase, passive-filter

When connecting equipment to the 3 phase mains, I have noticed high distortions in the mains voltages. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Spikes are caused by high power motor controllers which are connected to the same network.

Those spikes are causing some equipment to shutdown on over voltage protection.
I was thinking about ways to filter out those disturbances, unfortunately I haven't worked with 3 phase electrical systems before this case. The best solution which comes to my mind is to install LC low pass filter, however I wanted to pick something which is off-the-shelf. As far as I understand, all EMI/EMC filters don't fit the purpose, because they have common-mode chokes, but in my case I rather need inductors on separate cores, right?

Output current is expected to be at maximum 100 Amps.

Comment: Those motor controllers should have better line filtering on them.

Comment: *Those spikes are causing some equipment to shutdown on over voltage protection* - which equipment? Understand the threat and design a solution to protect the potential victim (things that are "shutting down")

Comment: The local regulatory agencies are going to have something to say about you attaching homebrew equipment to AC mains, so your best bet *by far* is to seek a COTS solution.  Surge suppressors are perfectly common.  They just wrestle the voltage spike down by using a VBO device of one kind or another.